# Best UX for a sudden Theme change

Tags: changes

I'm currently working on a project that is a partnership with another brand. The problem I'm having is as the customer is progressing through the application themed for the partner there is a point where if they don't meet a set criteria they are transferred to the customization step page in the flow with my company branding.

What is the best approach to make it so this isn't so jaring?

Comment: A good start is to consider the 'Principle of Least Astonishment'...There's no inherent issue in being redirected to a new theme, as long as users are informed when/why/what will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, going to look up this "Principle of Least Astonishment".

Answer (score 1):

When clicking on a link on my email app on my phone, the link opens in a browser, but there is still a header bar on the top of the screen with a back button to take me back to my mail.

Can you have a header at the top of the page (with the same color/style of the site that they just left) that communicates to the user "You have left site X so you can complete task Y. Click here to return to site X".

Comment: There currently isn't a way to go back to the previous page. Also, there is no alternate route the customer can take. If the customer could go back the only way forward for them is to go to where they just left. It's a very guided flow.

Comment: The banner idea was the main point to anchor the user. The back button was just an idea that was part of that.

Comment: I didn't mean to focus on the flow specifically. The banner approach is something I'm going to try/test. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to solve the problem visually there is still the issue of having to deal with potential changes to your brand or the partner's brand, so anything you try to fix here could easily result in more work later down the track.

I believe that something you should consider is through better focus and messaging for the user, and as long as they are aware of the change and the impact of this transition (i.e. where they are going, what they are doing and how they can get back if they need to) then you have achieved the main objective.

Once you have solved this problem then the visual changes will just help make the transition a little bit smoother, but you shouldn't rely on the visual design to do the heavy lifting here, it should be the messaging and directing the focus so they understand the change that they have to deal with.